# Remove 3rd party download widget from YouTube

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

Some time back I installed a widget in Chrome (Mac) to enable downloading of YouTube videos*. It looks like this...
[image: widget]

Since then I've found better ways, & this widget obscures useful information in the YouTube toolbar. I've gone through my Chrome extensions, & it isn't one of them. Can anyone tell me how to remove this widget?

* Yes, I know downloading violates YouTube's TOS, however there are legitimate reasons for downloading. In my case it's to use the video within another video that discusses the embedded one.

Comment: Can you consider re-install Google Chrome in order to get rid of this widget? - also, if you right-click on the widget and inspect the element - does it has any particular name you can search on the internet and maybe find the webpage that provides this widget and eventually find a unistaller? - please try and let us know.

Comment: Re-installing Chrome is a drastic step. The other suggestion is a good one, however it yielded no information that I could discern as useful.

Comment: Then, please search if there is a way to reset google chrome configurations. Do you have by any change another browser(s) and in those browsers are also installed this plugin? (*this is for check if in those broswers you have more chances to identify the widget to remove*). If you have your google account sincronized, you can download your bookmarks and (*once reinstalled*) you can recover your data - IIRC, you can even recover your browser history and previous closed tabs = consider also that probably that widget was removed and no information is available, making it harder to remove it.